# error C2664: cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' to 'std::wstring &

Tags: c++

```
error C2664: 'CCertStoreHelper::DeleteCtl' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' to 'std::wstring &error C2664: 'CCertStoreHelper::DeleteCtl' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' to 'std::wstring &
with
      [
              _Elem=wchar_t,
              _Traits=std::char_traits<wchar_t>,
              _Ax=std::allocator<wchar_t>
      ]
      Conversion loses qualifiers
```

I have no idea regarding this. So kindly provide the solution.

Code:

```
CCertStoreHelper certCaStore;
std::set<std::wstring> ctlIdentifiersToRemove; // It populates data which I m not mentioning


std::set<std::wstring>::iterator iter1;
std::set<std::wstring>::iterator iter2;

for(iter1 = ctlIdentifiersToRemove.begin(); iter1 != ctlIdentifiersToRemove.end(); iter1++)
{
    iter2 = ctlIdentifiersReferenced.find((*iter1));
    if(iter2 == ctlIdentifiersReferenced.end()) 
    {
        if(certCaStore.DeleteCtl((*iter1))) // error line
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
// prototype for DeleteCtl fun is
bool CCertStoreHelper::DeleteCtl(std::wstring &ctlIdentifier)
```

Kindly correct me what i am doing wrong
Thanks

Comment: Are you passing a temporary string object to the member function ? If that is the case, then the member should receive it by const reference. Show us the code snippet that causes the issue.

Comment: The important part is the "Conversion loses qualifiers" bit, and noticing that the error says it cannot convert from "const blahblahblah" to "bloobloobloo" (lacking the `const`)...

Comment: Please be kind enough to say which line of code the compiler is complaining about. That would save everybody a lot of time, and it's only polite to save the time of people who are volunteering to help.

Comment: Compiler complaining at this line: if(certCaStore.DeleteCtl((*iter1))) // error line

Comment: In my source code the braces are present for code block and there is also a code block.But the error is at this line.Being specific, I didn't mention code block here but in my project it is

Comment: So, I've edited your code to remove the ambiguity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As twalberg points out, the most important bit of the compiler error message is the "loses qualifiers" bit. It also tells you that it can't convert from `const std::wstring` to `std::wstring&`, except that it expanded the first `std::wstring` into its full template instantiation form.

The issue is that your `DeleteCtl` takes the argument by non-const reference, as if it wants to modify the string there (bad idea), but it can't do that, because you're iterating over a set, and you cannot change the members of a set once they're in there (`std::set` doesn't make a difference between `const_iterator` and `iterator`, essentially). The reason is that `std::set` bases its internal structure on the values of its elements, and if you change those values, the internal structure becomes invalid, and horrible things happen.

Comment: As you said I change the prototype of DeleteCtl to const reference and build successfully.Thanx for that.But now There is a Intellisense error is displaying what does it mean      IntelliSense: qualifiers dropped in binding reference of type "std::wstring &" to initializer of type "const std::wstring

Comment: Kindly provide the solution @Sebastian Redl

Comment: It means IntelliSense hasn't caught up yet, most likely.

Comment: Thanx Sebastian for your assistance